# Is it possible to capture a link in a facebook page that requires a login to be viewed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a candidate application link that was sent via email from facebook jobs. This link contains an html page where I could download the candidate's resume. And my goal is to scrape the data from this resume programmatically.

But when I access this link directly, an authentication page will require me to log in to view the content of it. So I'm thinking if it is possible in some way to login via code so I could access this link and scrape the necessary pieces of information?

Or is there some facebook restrictions or needed permissions that I should be aware of? I already have the facebook page access token where this job application is posted.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Facebook is actively hostile towards this kind of use case. I'm not familiar with this particular feature but when I attempted to write scripts to pull data from facebook I found they they do everything to block it so you visit the website instead.

Comment: Scraping any Facebook web pages is not allowed without their explicit prior written permission.